# Can I use 'axel' or 'aria2' to continue an interrupted 'wget' download?

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads, wget

I was downloading a big file with `wget`, but the speed was very slow. How can I continue downloading this file with `axel` or `aria2`?

Comment: It appears that `aget -c OFFSET` may work for you https://code.google.com/p/aget/

Comment: I think the reason why Milard asked about axel and aria2 is because of parallel downloads. `aget` doesn't offer it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, *axel* uses its own algorithm to split chunks and download them in parallel to one destination file. If you try with *axel*, it will overwrite the incomplete file and start from the beginning.

There isn't really a way to do this unless you manually (hex-editor, etc.) re-sort the incomplete file into the internal format used by Axel.

The same applies to *aria2*; it will also refuse to continue downloading an incomplete file not started with it. In that case, you would have to modify the `filename.aria2` metadata somehow to trick `aria2c` into resuming the file...

Comment: oh Thanks, but, how about aria2?

Comment: *aria2* will also refuse to continue downloading an incomplete file not started with it. You would have to modify the `filename.aria2` metadata somehow to trick *aria2* into doing so...

Comment: aria2c doesn't refuse to continue downloading if you set a `-c` flag as described in Stephen's answer.

Comment: Don't stop here! Both of them apparently can resume incomplete downloads. See the below answers for more details on how. [aria2c](https://askubuntu.com/a/163678/918989) / [axel](https://askubuntu.com/a/601870/918989)

Answer (score 6):

Try `aria2c -c url` in the directory your partial file is located.

Comment: This is described in aria2c's man page: 
> If the previous transfer is made by a browser or wget like sequential download manager, then use --continue option to continue the transfer.

Answer (score 4):

axel needs to be referenced by `-o filename` to continue:

```
axel url -o filename
```

Comment: `No state file, cannot resume!`